# What side effects a Mutex may have on system performance?

Tags: synchronization, embedded, real-time, mutex

Having a multithreaded application with shared resources their access need to be serialized using mutexes.

If I suppose the following conditions are satisfied by the application:

1 - No mutex misuse that leads to deadlocks, long waits or other disastrous results.

2 - Shared resources have accessors methods that handle all mutexes issues ( as an attempt to keep latecy caused by waiting for a mutex to be released short to the maximum).

Accepting that a mutex is a problem solver for many issues related to shared resources protection. Are there any side-effect on performance caused by using mutexes? If yes what should be the alternatives (maybe other synchronisation mechanism)?

To more clarify what I mean, I would consider the following example:

Thread A attempt to read a global variable shared between multiple threads. If I may consider that:

a - reading operation takes (X us).

b - Mutex use adds an overhead of (Y us).

c - read operation must not exceed Z us where Z >= X but Z < X + Y.

Then I think I may suppose that the Mutex ensured Mutual Exclusion but at the expense of a negative effect on performance (that could be slight or considerable impact depending on contexts).

Mutexes are useful in many situations, but are there any situations where they should be avoided  (or replaced) because of their negative effect on system performance despite of the fact they are used with care?

Note: Here I am referring to Mutexes offered as a kernel service. I don't mean any application implementation that try to imitate a Mutex (kernel service).

Answer (score 4):

If you're concerned about the amount of overhead added by getting a free mutex and then releasing it, then you shouldn't worry about that.  Yes, the code required to get and release a mutex adds a non-zero amount of overhead to the thread using the resource.  But in my experience that amount of overhead is negligible and I don't recall ever having to worry about it or work around it.  If you need a mutex to protect a shared resource then you should use a mutex.

If you're concerned that one thread might keep the resource too long, preventing another thread from accessing the resource in time, then that's a valid concern and that's where your care in system design comes in.  Some design techniques for addressing this concern include: minimizing the time a mutex is held, thread prioritization, and priority inheritance.

In some situations you can avoid using a mutex by restricting access to the resource to a single thread.  In other words, don't share the resource between threads.  Other threads that wish to use the resource must instead communicate with the resource's thread.  For example, you could have a single thread responsible for serial port transmissions.  Any other threads that need to send a serial message will post a request to the serial thread's mailbox or queue.  The serial thread simply pends on the mailbox/queue and then transmits any requests that are received.  This way there is no need for a mutex since the serial thread is the only thread that directly uses the resource.  Note that there is still some system design care required for this technique as multiple requests could stack up in the mailbox/queue causing some message transmissions to be delayed.

Comment: Actually, I am concerning about added overhead that can be caused by a mutex. I wanted to know whether there are some scenarios where using a mutex would introduce a nagging overhead regarding the application/Task purpose. Nevertheless, your comments are valuable. Thanks.